# How do I completely translate a page?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I want to develop a site in two languages. How do I completely translate a page?

For example, the menu tab and other places cannot be translated. I just can translate using the *Translate* tab.

> [image: screenshot]

In the following screenshot, the parts highlighted with a red box cannot be translated.

> [image: screenshot]

The language switch tab appears as in the following screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Have a read at the site building [Block languages](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279698) and [Menu translation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113982) documentation.

Comment: @NoSssweat Ok. I read it first. Are these can solve my problem right?

Comment: It depends on how the menus and the hero on that page is built. If it's a Drupal menu and blocks you can translate it through the UI. Maybe you need to enable multilingual options for them first.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of translations everything that is printed out on a Drupal page can be grouped under either **Interface** or **Content**.

Content (nodes, blocks) usually has the "Translate" tab/link visible somewhere near the other content editing links.

Interface text is most often translated through the **Translate interface > Translate** page. You can find it under the "Regional and language" settings.

Some modules provide on-screen or within-context translation tools for the interface text, but they all work on top of that "Translate interface" tool, so you can find all interface strings there.

The "Translate interface" tool is capitalization sensitive, so you have to enter the **exact** string as is written in the database or a module. "My Menu Item" is *not* the same as "My menu item".

To be able to see a string in the search results in the "Translate interface" tool you first have to visit the page where that text is shown in a non-default language in order for Drupal to record that string and make it available for translation.

Drupal is super flexible when it comes to multilingual setup and it allows you to pick which parts you want to translate and which parts you don't need translated or localized. That's why there are different modules responsible for translations of different parts of the interface. So keep in mind which modules you need to enable so you can translate features you have on your website.